# Visual C++: How is checked_array_iterator useful?

Tags: visual-c++, warnings, iterator

On compiling code at **Warning Level 4 (/W4)**, I get **[C4996](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttcz0bys.aspx)** warnings on `std::copy()` calls whose parameters are C arrays (not STL containers like vectors). The recommended solution to fix this seems to be to use [**stdext::checked_array_iterator**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985928.aspx).

What is the use of **stdext::checked_array_iterator**? How does it work?

Why does it not give any compile warning on this piece of erroneous code compiled under Visual C++ 2010?:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr0[5] = {100, 99, 98, 97, 96};
    int arr1[3];
    copy( arr0, arr0 + 5, stdext::checked_array_iterator<int*>( arr1, 3 ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This page, [Checked Iterators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985965%28v=VS.80%29.aspx), describe how it works, but this quote sums it up: *Checked iterators ensure that you do not overwrite the bounds of your container.*

So if you go outside the bounds of the iterator it'll either throw and exception or call `invalid_parameter`.

Comment: This doesn't truely answer the question