# error C4996: 'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe in c programming

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, c11, tr24731

I have created a small application to find max number by using user-defined function with parameter.  When I run it, it shows this message

> Error 1   error C4996: 'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe.
>   Consider using scanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use
>   _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

What do I do to resolve this?

This is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>

void findtwonumber(void);
void findthreenumber(void);

int main() {
    int n;
    printf("Fine Maximum of two number\n");
    printf("Fine Maximum of three number\n");

    printf("Choose one:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if (n == 1)
    {
        findtwonumber();
    }
    else if (n == 2)
    {
        findthreenumber();
    }
    return 0;
}

void findtwonumber(void)
{
    int a, b, max;
    printf("Enter a:");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Enter b:");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    if (a>b)
        max = a;
    else
        max = b;
    printf("The max is=%d", max);
}

void findthreenumber(void)
{
    int a, b, c, max;
    printf("Enter a:");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Enter b:");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    printf("Enter c:");
    scanf("%d", &c);
    if (a>b)
        max = a;
    else if (b>c)
        max = b;
    else if (c>a)
        max = c;
    printf("The max is=%d", max);
}
```

Comment: Well, it is a warning treated as an error. Either do as suggested, and replace `scanf` with `scanf_s`, or disable it as it is telling you..

Comment: See [Why does Visual Studio 2013 error on C4996?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20448102/why-does-visual-studio-2013-error-on-c4996)

Comment: just a compiler warning. scanf_s prevents possible buffer overflow.  see  http://code.wikia.com/wiki/Scanf_s

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is.  Either replace or disable with:
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Visual Studio 2013 error on C4996?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20448102/why-does-visual-studio-2013-error-on-c4996)

Comment: Related posts : [How to use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22450423/465053)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It sounds like it's just a compiler warning.

Usage of `scanf_s` prevents possible buffer overflow.
See:  http://code.wikia.com/wiki/Scanf_s

Good explanation as to why `scanf` can be dangerous: [Disadvantages of scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430303/disadvantages-of-scanf#answer-2430978)

So as suggested, you can try replacing `scanf` with `scanf_s` or disable the compiler warning.

Comment: How do I disable the compiler warning?

Comment: @VOLVO: To disable the compiler warning, add to the very top of your program the following statement: `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`.

Comment: The wikia link says `scanf_s` is " the same as `scanf`, except it is safe."  Is there any reason why an implementation that can support `scanf_s` should have `scanf` not chain to the same function?

Comment: @supercat: [Lots of them](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm), including efficiency and portability.

Comment: @DevSolar: That page doesn't even mention `scanf_s`.  Further, in most of the other examples of converting "normal" functions to "safe" functions, the proper replacement should have been `memcpy`.  For example, in the `string_dup` example, the page squawks that using `strcpy_s` adds a redundant string-length measurement, but the version with `strcpy` already included a redundant measurement.  A proper function should measure the source length once and then use `memcpy` to copy either everything or all but the last byte, and zero the last byte of the destination.

Comment: @supercat So first you ask for reasons. I point you to an *elaborate* paper by the standard conmittee on the Annex K "safe" functions (which by definition includes scanf_s even if you don't find it in a full-text search), and you start arguing fine print as if those guys didn't know what they are talking about. *Nice*.

Comment: @DevSolar: I had been asking *specifically* about `scanf_s`, which is not mentioned in the linked paper.  Otherwise, the paper correctly concludes that many of the functions are poorly designed and of dubious usefulness, but uses a rather weak argument (they can be used in ways that are less efficient than the originals without being safer) rather than a better argument (their corner-base behaviors are a poor fit for many the things programmers need to do).

Comment: @supercat: "Not mentioned in the paper" only if you skimmed through it looking for a good way to be contrary about it. In fact every single section of that paper contains at least one item that could be applied to `scanf_s`. Most importantly IMHO the part about Available Implementations. And if you *know* even better arguments than mentioned in the paper, why are you *asking* for them?

Answer (score 18):

Another way to suppress the error:  Add this line at the top in C/C++ file:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

Comment: To clarify: "at the top" means "before the `#include` lines". If you put it below `#include<stdio.h>`, for example, you'll still get the warning, because when you disable it it's already too late.

Comment: @FabioTurati has mentioned a very important point. Whenever we create a default CPP project then it creates `<projectName>.cpp` file containing `main` method. To refer all the header files it refers to a centralized header file named `stdafx.h` which contains all the include statements. So when I wrote `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` at the top of `<projectName>.cpp` file before all include statements then it made no difference. But when I added it to the top of `stdafx.h` file then finally the error went away.

Comment: Alternatively, add `/D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /wd4996` to your compile options.

Answer (score 16):

You can add "_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS" in Preprocessor Definitions.

Right-click your project->Properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++ ->Preprocessor->Preprocessor Definitions.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another way is when you create a new project, you don't click to Security Development Lifecycle (SDL) checks:

Or if you are in a project:
Right-click your `project->Properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++ ->All Options>`Sroll your mouse and find `SDL checks`, you edit it to `NO(/sdl-)`, then Apply, OK

Answer (score 1):

To disable the compiler warning, add to the very top of your program the following statement: `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is: the `scanf()` function reads the char/string starting from the first char to the first whitespace.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30266172)

Answer (score -1):

`#define scanf scan_f`

to replace the unsafe version with the safe.

Comment: The "secure" versions of the functions mentioned here have a different API to the standard API; you need to pass different arguments and handle a different result type. They also have different failure modes. This isn't something that `#define` can easily work around. (Also, `scan_f` is some third-party code.)