# scanf not working when reading float

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

float a;            //Initialize variables
char b;
int c;
char d;

int main(void)
{
    printf("Enter float: ");
    scanf("%4.2f", &a);

    printf("%4.2f", a);

    //printf("Enter character:\n");

    //printf("Enter 4-digit integer: \n");

    //printf("Enter character:\n");

    return 0;
}
```

However I get the following errors when compiling:

> 1.) `scanf`:unknown field type character '.' in format specifier
>
> 2.) `scanf`: too many arguments passed for format string

Can anyone explain what the issue in my code is?

Thank you!

Comment: It still seems to have build errors when I try to compile.  Hmmm....

Comment: I posted the two errors above.  The issue certainly has something to do with the scanf function.

Comment: That is exactly the code I have.  What could be causing it to not work on my end?  I am using Visual Studio 2015

Comment: I used scanf_s instead and it worked!  Why would scanf not work and scanf_s would?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30577519/error-c4996-scanf-this-function-or-variable-may-be-unsafe-in-c-programming this can answer all your queries.

Comment: Thankyou for your help sinsuren!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scanf("%f",&a)` does not take format specifier.

As mentioned in comments Visual Studio treat this warning as error.
So either use

```
scanf_s("%f",&a);
```

or go into settings and disable this warning as mentioned in this post [Why does Visual Studio 2013 error on C4996?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20448102/why-does-visual-studio-2013-error-on-c4996)

Answer (score 3):

You should not format the input. So just use `%f` as a first argument of `scanf`

```
scanf("%f", &a);
```

Answer (score 1):

use %lf for scanning double precision inputs