# Passing Dynamically Sized Arrays (a parameter is not allowed)

Tags: c++, c, arrays, visual-studio

I have a function signature that uses a parameter value to dynamically allocate an array of the correct size

```
void print(int rows, int cols, char arr[rows][cols])
```

I am currently working in the Visual Studio IDE. It seems to have a problem with not knowing what the parameter is and therefore not knowing how much memory to allocate. It is a syntax error and won't even compile. Is there a way to ignore the error/compiler warning. I previously had a scanf compiler warning but disabled it following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30577519/error-c4996-scanf-this-function-or-variable-may-be-unsafe-in-c-programming). Can I define something like

```
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
```

for this problem? Thanks

Comment: just show the compiler output for better description

Comment: Are you programming C or C++? It really makes a *big* difference since what you show for the function declaration is allowed in one language but not the other. Don't add unrelated language tags.

Comment: This doesn't look like valid C++. I think the third paramater must be a `char **arr`? Anyway, like @andrgolubev already said : Whats the compiler output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void print(int rows, int cols, char arr[rows][cols])
```

is not a valid declaration in C++. When a 2D array is passed, the value of the second dimension, `cols` in your case, must be known at compile time. The value of the first dimension may be compile time constant or be nothing but it can't be `rows`.

Valid declarations:

```
#define MAXCOLS 20
void print(int rows, int cols, char arr[][MAXCOLS])
```

and

```
#define MAXROWS 10
#define MAXCOLS 20
void print(int rows, int cols, char arr[MAXROWS][MAXCOLS])
```

and

```
#define MAXCOLS 20
void print(int rows, int cols, char (*arr)[MAXCOLS])
```

Answer (score 1):

At least in C++, you can't declare an array parameter using dimensions specified in other parameters, like you are attempting.

A 1-dimensional fixed array (`T[dim]`) can decay into a pointer (`T*`), so it is possible to do something like this:

```
void print(int rows, char *arr);

...

char arr[5];
print(5, arr);
```

However, when passing a multi-dimensional array, all but the first dimension must be explicitly specified, eg:

```
void print(int rows, int cols, char (*arr)[10])

...

char arr[5][10];
print(5, 10, arr);
```

Which does not help in your situation if you don't know how large the array is actually going to be (presumably that is why `cols` is being passed in to begin with).

However, this can be solved using a template instead:

```
template<const int rows, const int cols>
void print(char arr[rows][cols])

...

char arr[5][10];
print<5, 10>(arr);
```

Comment: That's a really bad and *incorrect* solution. A pointer to pointer is *not* equivalent to an array of arrays. An array of arrays is equivalent to a pointer to an array though, so for `char[5][10]` its equivalent type would be `char (*)[10]`. Also, the declaration shown by the OP *is* valid in C, which allows variable-length arrays. And we still don't know if the OP is programming in C or C++.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The user has a gold badge for c, I am certain this is just an honest mistake.