# C4996 'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using scanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

Tags: c, pragma

I want to solve this problem without "#pragma warning (disable:4996)" please help me.
I tried many things.
I think it may have problem with visual studio.

Comment: Define that symbol before including any headers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error C4996: 'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe in c programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30577519/error-c4996-scanf-this-function-or-variable-may-be-unsafe-in-c-programming)

Comment: If reopened, this should be closed as a duplicate of @JoeAmenta's suggested duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `scanf_s()` and make the necessary other changes, or `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`. Basically, read the error message and do what it suggests.

Note that `scanf_s()` requires extra arguments for the lengths of “string” arguments.