# Why is scanf in a for loop not working in visual studio. But it works dev c++?

Tags: c

[visual studio erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nIGb.png)

[dev c++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Neoeq.png)

this code is working in dev c++, ut not working visual studio. erro is

Error   C4996   'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using scanf_s instead.

code is...

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

    int arr[5] = { 0 };
    int i = 0;

    printf("Enter the number :");
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error C4996: 'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe in c programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30577519/error-c4996-scanf-this-function-or-variable-may-be-unsafe-in-c-programming)

Comment: Short answer: `scanf` doesn't provide protection from arithmetic overflow, thus, it's unsafe to use.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: `scanf` doesn't provide protection from arithmetic overflow, thus, it's unsafe to use.

Detailed answer:

The original issue begins with the **Buffer Overflow problem of gets in C**. Link: [Issue of `gets` and solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4346934)

It was because of `gets` function that one of first most widespread worm was able to propagate itself throughout the internet. Because `gets` overwrites the stack/memory allocated to variable used to store it. This leads to buffer overflow.

Scanf link: [Disadvantages of `scanf()` and its alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2430978/16571212)

Unlike `gets`, `scanf` does provide safety with string buffers by limiting the size, but, it is not possible for arithmetic input. Arithmetic input will overwrite the stack buffer. Although `scanf` provides a way to avoid buffer overflow problem with strings but, usually we (lazy programmers) won't specify the limits while using the `scanf`, hence we wrote an alternative `scanf_s`

Other alternatives of `scanf` are, `strtol`, `strtok`, and `atoi`, among others.

Edit 1: Changed from `sscanf` to `scanf_s` in ...hence, we wrote an alternative...

Comment: I guess yeah, typing mistake, sorry.