# "Disable Specific Warnings" compiler option not working

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2019

I am upgrading some legacy c++ code, to Visual Studio 2019, and am getting the "C4996" compiler error.

The "Disable Specific Warnings" build option is not working. I have confirmed that /wd"4996" is present in the command line. However, I still get the C4996 error, when I build. I followed [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-suppress-compiler-warnings?view=vs-2019)

```
char temp[256] = { 0 };
char *upper = strupr(temp);
```

I expect the build error to go away, however it persists.

Here is a screenshot, of a sample project, exhibiting the error:
[image]

Also, adding "#pragma warning(disable : 4996)" to the code, does eliminate the Warning/Error, as expected. However, this is not an ideal solution because of the large number of lines of code that would need to change. I am looking for a project wide solution, which to my knowledge "Disable Specific Warnings" should provide.

Comment: Why does the compiler output classify this as an error and not a warning?

Comment: What makes you believe this is a warning? The compiler seems to believe it is only an error and likely on purpose. This may help silence it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20448102/why-does-visual-studio-2013-error-on-c4996

Answer (score 0):

The problem was user error. I did not notice that the configurations were different for the property I was editing (Release), and the configuration I was building (Debug).

Setting "Disable Specific Warnings" in the proper configuration, works as expected.