# C4496 and C6387 for using strcpy and strcat

Tags: c

i am trying to copy 2 strings in a function, to a new dynamic memory by the strlen() function.

```
char* PairSortedArrays(char a[], char b[])
{
    char* p1 = (char*)malloc(strlen(a) + strlen(b) + 1);
    if(p1)
    {
    strcpy(p1, a);
    strcat(p1, b);
    }
    return p1;
}
```

Getting Compiler Error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C4996   'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.   check   C:\Users\97254\source\repos\check\check\Source.c    35
```

Comment: i have errors C4996 and C6387

Comment: You do not check the return value of `malloc()`

Comment: i added if(p1) and it still has the error C4496

Comment: Which compiler are you using and it's version?

Comment: check for the [Why does Visual Studio 2013 error on C4996?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20448102/why-does-visual-studio-2013-error-on-c4996). if it can solve your problem.

Comment: Code is fine.  Disable [EEE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embrace,_extend,_and_extinguish) warning with [#pragma warning(disable : 4996)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49016331/2410359)

Answer (score 1):

Do not use strcat as you have all the information available.

```
char *strdupcat(const char *str1, const char *str2)
{
    size_t str1Len;
    char *result = NULL;

    if(str1 && str2)
    {
        result = malloc((str1Len = strlen(str1)) + strlen(str2) + 1);
        if(result)
        {
            strcpy(result, str1);
            strcpy(result + str1Len, str2)
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: @TruthSeeker C has a long, sad and ongoing history of buffer overflows. While sometimes you know the copy is safe, all too often functions like `strcpy` and `strcat` are used without being certain. They are so easy to mis-use, that their use is considered always bad. Use the safer alternatives.

Comment: which is the safer alternatives?

Comment: `memcpy` is safer than `strcpy` [link](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html)

Comment: In this case it does not matter as strlen is used and it will fail on this funcction if we read from the unalocated memory. If not we will allocate enough memory even for the bad srings.

Comment: memcpy is same unsafe as strcpy

Comment: This answer nicely avoids the waste of [`strcat()`](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is part of your actual problem but strcpy() is not safe and can cause buffer overflows. By the way, your compiler should not fail to compile just because of this.. But based on a microsoft post :

" Some C runtime library functions are deprecated because they're insecure and have a more secure variant. Others are deprecated because they're obsolete. "

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-3-c4996?view=vs-2019

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

The older string function, less secure version is marked as deprecated and the new version has the _s ("secure") suffix (**example**: strcpy_s).

In your case,

**"strcpy"** function has no way of telling, whether the source string which you are copying is too big for its destination buffer.

But in secure **"strcpy_s"**, takes the size of the buffer as a parameter, so it can determine if a buffer overrun will occur.

**Example:**

If you use strcpy_s to copy eleven characters into a ten-character buffer, that is an error on your part; strcpy_s cannot correct your mistake, but it can detect your error and inform you by invoking the invalid parameter handler.