# C6387 for memcpy, strcpy and strcpy_s

Tags: c, warnings, memcpy, buffer-overflow, strcpy

It seems that I cannot shake the C6387 warning.

```
typedef struct HashBind{
    char* cKeyIdentifier;
    void* vValue;
} HashBind;

....
    
HashBind* strNewBind = malloc(sizeof(HashBind));    
strNewBind -> cKeyIdentifier = (char*) malloc((strlen(pcKey) + 1) * sizeof(char));
            
memcpy(strNewBind -> cKeyIdentifier, pcKey, strlen(pcKey + 1));
```

with pcKey being a const char* type. How can I get past the

> Warning   C6387   'strNewBind->cKeyIdentifier' could be '0':  this does not adhere to the specification for the function 'memcpy'.

Same applies when I try to use strcpy or strcpy_s, instead of memcpy. Any ideas or any alternatives? How do I skip this unsafe use of of strcpy/memcpy (prevent buffer overflow)? [C4496 and C6387 for using strcpy and strcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59467803/c4496-and-c6387-for-using-strcpy-and-strcat) didn't help much :/

Comment: Probably the compiler is realizing that you are not checking the return of malloc, so if allocation fails and it returns NULL, you would be passing a NULL to memcpy

Comment: That simple... A quick if check statement after malloc and the warning is gone! Mill thanks for you time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 'strNewBind->cKeyIdentifier' could be '0': this does not adhere to the specification for the function 'memcpy'.

Test for a `NULL` return from `malloc()`.

```
size_t n = (strlen(pcKey) + 1) * sizeof(char);
strNewBind->cKeyIdentifier = malloc(n);

// Add test
if (strNewBind->cKeyIdentifier) {            
  memcpy(strNewBind -> cKeyIdentifier, pcKey, n);
} else {
  Handle_OutOfMemory(); // TBD code.
}
```